# Mean and variance of sample mean $\bar X$

Tags: probability, statistics

Determine the mean and variance of the sampe mean $\bar X = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{5}X_i}{5}$ where $X_1,..X_5$ is random sample from a distribtuion having pdf $f(x)=4x^3$, $0<x<1$, zero elsewhere.

It's an unsolved problem from my exercise with no answer and solution. So i just wanted to know if i did solve it in right manner. Correct me if i did wrong. 
My results after solving are:

$E(\bar X)=\dfrac{4}{5}$

$E(\bar X^{2})=\dfrac{4}{6}$

$V(\bar X)=\dfrac{4}{6}-\dfrac{16}{25}=\dfrac{2}{75}$

Comment: You seem to have worked out the values for each $X_i$ rather than $\bar{X}$. The latter will have the same expectation but a smaller variance

Comment: @Henry   I have to divide variance by 5 in this case i guess?

Comment: Indeed you do..

Comment: @Henry Please look at this question my variance coming out to be $45.303$ but answer given is $30.6$ Just tell me if my answer is wrong.http://prntscr.com/i4vn1q

Comment: ask another question for that, showing your working (including $\rho=\frac12$)

Comment: @Henry Silly me i didn't take $2$ with covariance. Thanks anyways.